# Check url for if condition

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have the following condition for wordpress site:

```
if (is_page(array(1111, ???)) {
//do something for page# 1111 and url that contains "names"
}
```

I have a page that has url as following:

```
example.com/names/steve
example.com/names/mike
```

So, I want to check  if the url is "names" as the condition.

Can someone tell me how to change the condition to check for "names" in the url?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I changed to the following but no luck yet.

```
if ((is_page(1111)) || (preg_match("/\/names$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) 

or

if ((is_page(1111)) || (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'names')) 

or

if ((is_page(1111)) || (strpos($url, 'names') !== false))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `strpos($url, 'names') !== false`

Comment: you use un-need brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `preg_match()` function using regular expression:

```
<?php
    $url = 'example.com/names/steve';
    echo (preg_match("/names/i", $url)) ? 'Match' : 'No Match';
?>
```

so for your example try this:

```
if (is_page(1111) || preg_match("/\/names\//", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
   // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$myArray = explode("/", $link);
$page = end($myArray);
if($page == '1111') {
  //Your code
}
```

Edit: In case URL contains trailing slash (or not)

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$actual_link = rtrim('/', $link);
$myArray = explode("/", $actual_link);
$page = end($myArray);
if($page == '1111') {
  //Your code
}
```